# How to set response date format in rest assured mock mvc while testing spring could contract for a web service?

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, spring-cloud-contract

I am using tests generated by spring cloud contracts to test web service response. 
The service used to return date as timestamp, now with the updated Spring version (2.0.5) dates are returned in the "2018-11-30T21:16:18.220+0000" format. The contract tests are still passing without any change. I learned that this is because Spring could contract uses RestAssuredMockMvc which is unaware of springs application configs. How can I change the config in the contracts to make sure that contracts always check for the date in same format as that are correctly returned by the service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either add the missing configuration to the mockmvc rest assured setup or use explicit mode of tests generation and setup a real spring boot context

Comment: thanks, how can I add configuration to rest assured mock mvc, is there an equivalent of application.properties?

Comment: Check out `RestAssuredMockMvc.webAppContextSetup(...,...) `where you can pass the web application context and `MockMvcConfigurerAdapter` and set all the values you need to. Another (faster) option is to use `RestAssuredMockMvc.standaloneSetup()` and pass in the `MockMvcBuilder` that allows you to pass additional configuration. You can use the `MockMvcBuilders` class to create a `MockMvc` instance. If you use webappcontext then your Spring's jackson config will be picked. For standalone one you have to setup the `RestAssuredMockMvcConfig.config().objectMapperConfig`

Answer (score 3):

For Spring Boot application, simple way to execute `RestAssured` against spring application setup is:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest
// or @SpringBootTest
public abstract class BaseContractTest {

    @Autowired
    protected MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        RestAssuredMockMvc.mockMvc(mockMvc);
    }
}
```

Version with @WebTestClient runs faster but needs mocking services, version with @SpringBootTest runs slower but utilize whole application.

Proposed in previous answer `RestAssuredMockMvc.webAppContextSetup()` is very similar to version with @SpringBootTest. The second proposition, `RestAssuredMockMvc.standaloneSetup()`, requires a complicated configuration, different than Spring application configuration.

For that reason `RestAssuredMockMvc.standaloneSetup()` is error prone and worse than `@WebMvcTest`.

`RestAssuredMockMvc.webAppContextSetup()` is OK

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](https://medium.com/@vicusbass/datetime-serialization-in-spring-tests-5d31ccd025c).

Setup object mapper with RestAssuredMockMvc.standaloneSetup

```
RestAssuredMockMvc.standaloneSetup(
                MockMvcBuilders
                        .standaloneSetup(yourcontroller).setMessageConverters(mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter)
        );
```